# Passing numbers to MVC controller using Angular 2 http operation

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angular

I am trying to pass `id` from angular 2 to Asp.net mvc controller but getting error `Internal server Errror`

My Component Code is:

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from "@angular/core";
import { Products } from "../Models/products";
import { Http, Headers } from "@angular/http";
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    template: 'This Is Category {{id}}'
})
export class CategoryComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    private products: Products[];
    id: number;
    private sub: any;
    constructor(private http: Http, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }
    ngOnInit() {
        debugger;
        this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
            this.id = +params['id']; // (+) converts string 'id' to a number
        });

        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        this.http.post("/Products/GetProductByCategory", JSON.stringify(this.id), { headers: headers }).subscribe(data => {
            let body = data.text();
            debugger;
            this.products = JSON.parse(body);
        });
    }
    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.sub.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

My Asp net Controller code is:

```
   public JsonResult GetProductByCategory(int id)
        {
            List<ProductsModel> productList = new List<ProductsModel>();
            productList = productBl.GetProductByCategory(id);
            JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            js.Serialize(productList);
            return Json(productList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Can anyone tell me whats wrong with my code . Thanks in advance

Comment: one problem I see is that you use an `async` as being `sync`. You should put the post inside the `subscribe`

Comment: How can you please provide me an answer?

Comment: IMO this should be a `GET` request and the `id` should be passed via route or query string. Also read about gotchas while sending primitive types to web api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO this should be a `GET` request respecting the HTTP and the id should be passed as route value or query string.

`this.http.get("/Products/GetProductByCategory?id="+this.id,...)`

Answer (score 2):

To get rid of the async issue you can move the call to your subscription, although I am not sure this will fix the internal server error:

```
ngOnInit() {
    debugger;
    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
        this.id = +params['id']; // (+) converts string 'id' to a number
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        this.http.post("/Products/GetProductByCategory", JSON.stringify(this.id), { headers: headers }).subscribe(data => {
           let body = data.text();
           debugger;
           this.products = JSON.parse(body);
       });
    }); 
}
```

Comment: The Problem is in  `JSON.stringify(this.id)` when i remove this it Works